# How do the two program counter registers work in the 6502?

Tags: 6502, program-counter

I am currently developing a subset of the 6502 in LogiSim and at the current stage I am determining which parts to implement and what can be cut out. One of my main resources is [Hanson's Block Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxwKp.jpg).

I am currently trying to determine how exactly the increment logic works. In a previous project that I worked on in school, the program counter was incremented via a single instruction coming from the decoded instruction memory. In this diagram, the program counter logic looks like it works differently than I have previously encountered.

[image: The portion that is confusing]

How exactly does this logic work and does it use an instruction from the instruction memory to increment? As a follow up, Is it possible to simplify the program counter logic to use one or two instructions from the instruction memory to increment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 6502 has only one program counter. It is 16 bits wide. Because a lot of other things in the CPU are exactly 8 bits wide, it makes hardware sense to cut the 16 bit program counter into two halves, so that each half fits in 8 bits. For example, each half is loaded separately, one by one, with an instruction like `JMP`. And the relative branch instructions bring `PCL` to an ALU input.

Those halves are just called `PCH` and `PCL` internally. You can see that `PCL` has increment logic attached to it, and one of the outputs is a carry out signal called `PCLC`. That's the input to *another* circuit that increments `PCH`.

None of this matters to a program. The program just cares that `PC` points to the instruction that's going to be executed next, and uses that fact to influence its own flow. But if you're interested in knowing more of these details, I'll point you to the Visual6502 simulation. It's much more accurate and detailed than Hanson's Block Diagram.

Comment: I am no longer working on this project, but I'm sure others would get value out of this great answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! How did your project go?

Comment: I somewhat completed it, it was passed on to others when I left (this was my HS capstone project - to build the 6502 in logisim to develop a curriculum for students to do the same) -- Main thing I ever got to was programming the logic, most circuitry got done.